# Can I safely delete MS SQL Server Error Log?

Tags: sql-server-2008, log-files

I have some huge log files, which are taking up all the space on a PC's hard drive. Is ok to simply delete the log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSQQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG.1 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3587611/Cycling-the-ERRORLOG-file-and-Deleting-Backup-History-Information.htm) discusses configuring log rotation limits (see [management studio express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx)).  According to [the definition of the error log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885.aspx), it does not seem to be essential for your instance to run properly.  I would say it is safe to delete, but you likely want to configure rotation.